# Ignoring statements based on null parameters in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that contains a bunch of parameters. They will never all contain values, some will be null.

How do I ignore these insert statements if the parameters are null?

Using firebug for firefox it is telling me that my database columns can't contain nulls, which is why I believe I have incorrectly coded this stored procedure (I am using jQuery ajax and a web service to communicate with this stored procedure).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Vehicle_InsertAll
    @Make  varchar,
    @Model  varchar,
    @SubModel varchar,
    @Liter decimal,
    @Cylinder varchar,
    @Fuel varchar,
    @FuelDel varchar,
    @Asp varchar,
    @EngDesg varchar
AS
IF @Make IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VehicleMakes (VehicleMake) VALUES(@Make)
    END
    IF @Model IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VehicleModels (Name) VALUES(@Model)
    END
    IF @SubModel IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VehicleSubModels (Name) VALUES(@SubModel)
    END
    IF @Liter IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VehicleLiters (Liters) VALUES(@Liter)
    END
    IF @Cylinder IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VehicleCylinders (Cylinders) VALUES(@Cylinder)
    END
    IF @Fuel IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VehicleFuel (FuelType) VALUES (@Fuel)
    END
    IF @FuelDel IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VehicleFuelDelivery (Delivery) VALUES (@FuelDel)
    END
    IF @Asp IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VehicleAspiration (Asp) VALUES (@Asp)
    END
    IF @EngDesg IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VehicleEngDesg (Designation) VALUES (@EngDesg)
    END

    RETURN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stored procedure shouldn't be trying to insert `NULL`s into any table. Your `IF` statements are preventing that. Are you sure the error message isn't telling you that the parameters can't be `NULL`? If so, the way to fix it is just to give the parameters default values:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Vehicle_InsertAll
    @Make  varchar = null,
    @Model  varchar = null,
    @SubModel varchar = null,
    @Liter decimal = null,
    @Cylinder varchar = null,
    @Fuel varchar = null,
    @FuelDel varchar = null,
    @Asp varchar = null,
    @EngDesg varchar = null
AS
<Stored Procedure Statements>
```

I'd also suggest explicitly declaring the size of all your varchar and decimal parameters as well, rather than relying on the defaults.

Comment: So the problem ended up being that when I get the value of a blank textbox in jquery and pass to my web service using json, json apparently isn't passing a null value to the webservice.